# Python String to Float with 8 decimal point conversion

Tags: python

Below is my String.

```
str = '0.00007515'
```

tried below

```
mainValue = float(str)  gives me 7.515e-05 output.
 mainValue =Decimal(str) gives me 0.0 output
```

I wanted to output in 0.00007515 float or other datatype.
How can i solve this.

Comment: Are you sure about the `Decimal(str)` output? If it's giving `0.0`, that would be a rather surprising bug.

Comment: It is very likely they changed the precision of decimal. You need to understand the difference of a number and display formats

Comment: @JBernardo: Changing the precision of the `decimal` module wouldn't give `0.0` here.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes M sure on this using python 3.7.0 version

Comment: @vinod: In that case, I suspect you're not showing us the actual code you're using. To be clear, there's really no way that `Decimal('0.00007515')` is going to give you an output of `0.0`.

Comment: let me add it @MarkDickinson

Comment: @MarkDickinson sorry my bad i was printing another value you are right. decimal is working properly thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify that you need 8 digits after the decimal point when printing the value!

```
mainValue = float(str)
print("{:.8f}".format(mainValue))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying this m using below code.

    print("{:.8f}".format(client.get_orderbook_ticker(symbol=ticker)['askPrice']))

and throwing me error ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: @vinod Then you must convert it to `float` before trying to use this format solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple format function with precision you need.

```
print("{0:.8f}".format(float(str)))
```